# Does the differential for smooth maps between manifolds induce a type of cohomology?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $f: M \to N$ be an immersion between smooth manifolds to make things simpler. We can think of $df : TM \to TN$ as a bundle map, defined in the natural way as $df|_{T_p M} = df_p : T_p M \to T_{f(p)}N$.

Thus, the differential $d$ maps $C^\infty (M,N)$ into $\text{Hom} (TM, TN)$, the space of bundle maps from $TM$ to $TN$. I am looking for a way or some trick to tell when some $\varphi \in \text{Hom}(TM,TN)$ is the differential of an immersion $f$.

This feels like a cohomological question to me, if I put it as follows:

Is there some vector space $V$ such that $$C^\infty (M,N) \xrightarrow{d_1} \text{Hom}(TM,TN) \xrightarrow{d_2} V \xrightarrow{d_3} \ldots$$ is the beginning of a complex for some kind of cohomology? (**EDIT:** $\text{Hom}(TM, TN)$ is not a vector space in general, if $M \neq N$. The construction I'm looking for doesn't work, is there a way to salvage it?) One would also need to define how $d_k$ behaves in the second arrow and beyond of course.

If this works out, I would hope to get some sequence of cohomological groups $H^k$ defined in terms of $M$ and $N$, where $H^0$ would correspond to the constant functions in $C^\infty (M,N)$ and $H^1 = Ker(d_2)/Im(d_1)$ would be some finite dimensional vector space where the $0$ equivalence class corresponds to differentials of functions.

Is something like this known? Does this question/setup even make sense? Otherwise, how would I start to look for this $V$ and define $d_2$? Thanks.

Comment: I do not really understand the question in the 2nd paragraph: Each $\varphi$ comes with a map $f: M\to N$, and if $\varphi=dg$, then $g=f$. Of course, you need not have $\varphi=df$ in general. If you want to study this question "up to homotopy" then an answer is given by the Hirsch-Smale h-principle.

Comment: How is this a bundle map unless you take it as a section of $\text{Hom}(TM, f^*TN)$? Don’t you need a map to cover on the base spaces?

Comment: @TedShifrin Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but given the map $f: M \to N$ which covers the base spaces, $df : TM \to TN$ fits the definition of a bundle  map since it maps fibers to fibers linearly, $T_pM \to T_f(p) N$

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yeah by "$\varphi$ is the differential of an immersion $f$" I meant $\varphi = df$, which as you say is not guaranteed for all such bundle maps. Thanks for the pointer to the h-principle, I'll check it out.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Oh you're right, both base spaces need to be the same to make it a vector space... I guess the construction I hoped for wouldn't work in this case

Comment: "I am looking for a way or some trick to tell when some φ∈Hom(TM,TN) is the differential of an immersion f." This question (up to homotopy) is answered by h-principle techniques. Look up the Smale-Hirsch theorem (just not on wolfram, it is stated incorrectly).