# When is a bundle map between tangent bundles the differential of a function?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610452/does-the-differential-for-smooth-maps-between-manifolds-induce-a-type-of-cohomol), but stated in a simpler and clearer manner.

Let $\varphi : TM \to TN$ be a bundle map between tangent bundles of two smooth manifolds.

> When is $\varphi = df$ for some $f \in C^\infty (M,N)$?

In my previous question I wanted $f$ to be an immersion, but now I'm relaxing that condition and asking a more general question. Is the h-principle still the go-to method of attack for this type of problem?

Comment: The problem with this question is that $\phi$ itself defines a map $\Phi: M \rightarrow N$, since, by the definition of a bundle map, for each $x \in M$, $\phi(T_xM) \subset T_yN$ for some $y \in N$. So if $\phi = df$ for some $f$, then $f = \Phi$. So the question becomes when is $\phi = d\Phi$?

Comment: I see that in response to your previous question, @MoisheKohan made a comment almost identical to mine above.